# org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender not working in linux

Tags: log4j

I am using org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender to generate daily logs.
It generates daily logs in windows, but it is not generating logs in linux.
Help is greatly appreciated!
Below is the log4j.xml file:

```
            <param name="append" value="true" />
            <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />


<rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
  <param name="FileNamePattern" value="D:/source/logs/passports.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"/>
</rollingPolicy>

<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                    <!-- The log message pattern -->
                    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p {%c} %m%n" />
            </layout>
```

```
     <root>
            <priority value="info,debug,error" />
            <appender-ref ref="ROLL" />
    </root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your FileNamePattern needs to reflect the location of the file, specific to the server/workstation the application is running in.

In the snippet you gave, I see that the value for FileNamePattern is `D:/source/logs/passports.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log`.

The "D:" suggests to me that this is for your windows box.

Replace this value with the location that your linux box would hold the log file, for example: `/var/source/logs/passports.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log`